# Xamarin - Câmera não funciona

Tags: html5, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Desenvolvi uma aplicação Web. Entretanto, na WebView que eu criei dessa aplicação, quando eu tento fazer upload de arquivos, o código me redireciona para a galeria de imagens ao invés de abrir a câmera do celular.

No meu HTML, eu tenho o seguinte campo:

```html
<input name="localFoto[]" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Como faço para resolver?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Cordova - Câmera não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/353330/cordova-c%c3%a2mera-n%c3%a3o-funciona)

Comment: Acho que isso tem pouco a ver com `xamarin`. Talvez possa encontrar mais ajuda com as tags adequadas, infelizmente também não sei quais seriam para poder sugerir na edição.

Answer (score 0):

Achei a Solução: https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera

É com JavaScript e HTML testa aí!
Achei show de bola nem sabia que tinha como fazer isso.

Caso o Link saia do Ar...

HTML

```
<!--
    Ideally these elements aren't created until it's confirmed that the 
    client supports video/camera, but for the sake of illustrating the 
    elements involved, they are created with markup (not JavaScript)
-->
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

JavaScript

```
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Get access to the camera!
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
    });
}

/* Legacy code below: getUserMedia 
else if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
    navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true }, function(stream) {
        video.src = stream;
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
} else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ video: true }, function(stream){
        video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
} else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Mozilla-prefixed
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia({ video: true }, function(stream){
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
}
*/
```

Fonte: https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera

Comment: Vinicius, eu testei o código acima, porém ele não funciona no Google Chrome do celular e nem no Xamarin.

Comment: Tentou descomentando os else if?

Comment: Sim. Infelizmente, não funcionou.